# Adding a 3rd chain to langchain to output multiple prompts

Tags: python, langchain

I have been following some tutorials on langchain and I have got a little stuck regarding generating an output from some inputs. Basically what I am trying to do is:

1. Input only the "cuisine"
2. From this, it generates a restaurante name,
3. The restaurante name gets passed to another sequentialchain to give me menu items
4. **Stuck here** - I want to pass each menu item to a new chain in order to get the ingredients needed for this recipe.
5. If possible, I would also like to see how I can take steps 4 results for each menu item and generate a recipe using each of the ingredients

Code:

```
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.chains import LLMChain
from langchain.chains import SimpleSequentialChain
from langchain.chains import SequentialChain

openai_key = ""

# Sequential chain
llm = OpenAI(temperature=0.6, openai_api_key = openai_key)

########## Chain 1 - Restaurant Name

prompt_template_name = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables = ['cuisine'],
    template = "I want to open a restaurant for {cuisine} food. Suggest a fancy name for this."
)

name_chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt_template_name, output_key="restaurante_name")



######### Chain 2 - Menu Items

prompt_template_items = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables = ['restaurante_name'],
    template = """Suggest some menu items for {restaurante_name}. Return it as a comma separated list"""
)

food_items_chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt_template_items, output_key="menu_items")

chain = SequentialChain(
    chains = [name_chain, food_items_chain],
        input_variables = ['cuisine'],
        output_variables = ['restaurante_name', 'menu_items']
)

print(
    chain({'cuisine': 'Spanish'})
)


######## Chain 3 - Menu recipies

prompt_template_ingredients = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables = ['recipe_ingredients'],
    template = """List the ingrediants for {recipe_ingredients}. Renturn it as a comma separated list"""
)

ingredients_chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt_template_ingredients, output_key="ingredient_items")

chain = SequentialChain(
    chains = [name_chain, food_items_chain, ingredients_chain],
    input_variables = ['cuisine', 'restaurante_name'],
    output_variables = ['restaurante_name', 'menu_items', 'ingredient_items']
    )

print(
    chain({'cuisine': 'American'})
    )
```